# AJAX response not displayed immediately in IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I'm seeing a strange issue with my code below. The content received thru the xmlHttpRequest, is not being displayed in IE8, after clicking the link. It is displayed only after moving the mouse/cursor, after clicking the link.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script language="javascript">
         var xmlHttpfunction;

         function ShowHint(str,id,currentid,count)
         {
            for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
               if (i == currentid)
               {
                  cellImg(i,'images/head_on.jpg');
               }
               else
               {
                  cellImg(i,'images/btn_img.jpg');
               }
            }
            xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

            if (xmlHttp == null)
            {
               alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
               return;
            }

            var url = "myurl.php";
            url = url+"?id="+id;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
            xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
         }

         function cellImg(idCell, imgName)
         {
            document.getElementById(idCell).style.background = "url(" + imgName + ")";
         }

         function stateChanged()
         {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState === 1)
            {
               document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = "<p align='center'><img src='images/wait.gif'></p>";
            }
            else if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4)
            {
               document.getElementById("element").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
         }

     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="navigation">
        <ul >
           <li id=1 >
              <a href="#" onclick="ShowHint('menu',42,1,18);return false;">
                 Item 1
              </a>
           </li>
           <li id=2 >
              <a href="#" onclick="ShowHint('menu',11,2,18);return false;">
                 Item 2
              </a>
           </li>
           <li id=3 >
              <a href="#" onclick="ShowHint('menu',12,3,18);return false;">
                 Item 3
              </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="element" id="element">
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above works on Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera. But on IE8, the content is not displayed (though it is loaded into the innerHTML of the div id="element"), if there is no cursor movement, after clicking the link.

I've tried putting alerts and debugging thru IE8's script debugger (in Tools->DeveloperTools), but could not find whats causing the issue.

Could anyone help me out on this, please ?

Many Thanks,
sgullap

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if perhaps the responseText from the ajax call is starting with a carriage return.  I had a similar issue today (which is how I found this question while googling) and discovered that my HTML code accidentally started with a blank line in the target page of the ajax call.  Removing that extra line caused the innerHTML to be set correctly and to display.

I'm not sure I understand WHY this caused IE not to display the innerHTML that I assigned to the div, but know now to make doubly sure to avoid blank lines at the top of any HTML output retrieved through ajax!